# Generador de cuentas con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy armando un generador de cuentas simple con HTML y JavaScript, he estado buscando algunas ayuda como por ej limitar a una cuenta por persona es decir si quiere alguien generar una cuenta le da click al boton y de ahi se bloquea o con cookies desactivar temporalmente el generador para esa "x" persona.

Les dejo mi código de ejemplo

```
<form name="form_cuenta">
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    <div id="tx" class="form-control"></div>
    <script>
      var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var result;
      var i;
      if (getCookie('id')) {
        i = getCookie('id');
      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
      client.open('GET', 'http://unc3ns0r3d.ml/cuentasnetflix.txt');
      client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        result = client.responseText;
        document.getElementById("tx").innerHTML = result.split('\n')[i];
        i++;
      }
      client.send();

      function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }
        }
        return "";
      }

      function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
      }

      function next(i) {
        document.getElementById("tx").innerHTML = result.split('\n')[i];
      }

      function nextl() {
        i = getCookie('id');
        next(i);
        i++;
        setCookie('id', i, 8);
      }
    </script>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-group" style="text-align: center;" id="center">
    <hr> Tipo de cuenta:<br /><br />
    <select class="form-control chosen-select" name="selector" data-placeholder="Tipo de cuentas">
              <option id="c_netflix">Netflix</option>
         </select>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group no-margn">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Generar" onclick="nextl();">
  </div>
```

**Bueno para los que aun no entienden mi idea, el generador lee un archivo del texto pero en si quiero que la linea o cuenta que se da ya no aparezca en el texto y con las cookies bloquee que genere otra cuenta a esa persona**

Estuve buscando en muchos lados de como hacer algo asi pero solo encuentro hacerlo con PHP y DB para hacerlo mas fácil.

Comment: Para aplicaciones en producción normalmente cuando se generan cuentas se hace en el backend.

Comment: @Antony999k Si, creo que ire por el lado del backend, ya que no creo que me salga como quiero en javascript